# Portfolio tracker not automatically updating / JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am not a programmer but I can read and understand the logic behind a code. In order to track my portfolio's performance, I used a script I found online that allows me to get updated prices automatically. I adapted the script to my requirements: I didn't need the dashboard and the margin email notifications. Additionally, I added a time-based trigger that automatically refreshes the file and the figures every 5 minutes.

[My dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2Bs5.png)

However, for some reason the file is not updating automatically every 5 minutes and is not returning the message: "Rates were last updated at TIME".

Also, by comparing my sheet with the original one (link below), I noticed that this could be due to the following:

- I removed BTC from where it was positioned.
- I removed the contents in column A, Rows 2 and 3 which contained the formulas: =MATCH("BTC", B:B,0) / =MATCH("ETH", B:B,0)
- I removed this formula from Column D, Row 27: =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(A2+1,9))

**Original sheet and script:** https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t3tX22qEIK0HmgXgwiI0kxCLkBWFSSfusGGvxULWO1I/edit

Any help is appreciated :)

Here's the code:

```
function RefreshImports() {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  if (!lock.tryLock(5000)) return; 

  var id = "1IVUjHDRxJiWw8H1LYY_IY0_ydwZ4F3qfSHKcKLa78Bw";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Profit/Loss");
  var rowRef = sheet.getRange(2,1).getValue();
  var active = sheet.getRange(8 + rowRef,8).getValue();

  if (active == 1) {
    var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
    var formulas = dataRange.getFormulas();
    var content = "";
    var now = new Date();
    var time = now.getTime();
    var re = /.*[^a-z0-9]import(?:xml|data|feed|html|range|regex|json)\(.*/gi;
    var re2 = /((\?|&)(update=[0-9]*))/gi;

    for (var row=0; row<formulas.length; row++) {
      for (var col=0; col<formulas[0].length; col++) {
        content = formulas[row][col];
        if (content != "") {
          var match = content.search(re);
          if (match !== -1 ) {
            var url = sheet.getRange(row + 1, col).getValue();

            if (url != "") {
              var updatedContent = url.toString().replace(re2,"?update=" + time);
              if (updatedContent == url) {
                // No querystring exists yet in url
                updatedContent = url.toString() + "?update=" + time;
              }
              // Update url in formula with querystring param
              sheet.getRange(row + 1, col).setValue(updatedContent);

              Utilities.sleep(250);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // Done refresh; release the lock.
    lock.releaseLock();     

    var dateStr = now.toLocaleDateString("en-GB", { timeZone: 'Lebanon/Beirut' });
    var timeStr = now.toLocaleTimeString("en-GB", { timeZone: 'Lebanon/Beirut' });

    // Show last updated time on sheet somewhere
    sheet.getRange(4 + rowRef,2).setValue("Rates were last updated at " + timeStr);
  }
}

function importRegex(url, regexInput) {
  var output = '';
  var fetchedUrl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  if (fetchedUrl) {
    var html = fetchedUrl.getContentText();
    if (html.length && regexInput.length) {
      output = html.match(new RegExp(regexInput, 'i'))[1];
    }
  }
  // Grace period to not overload
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  return unescapeHTML(output);
}

function importJson(address) {
  var output = '';
  var fetchedUrl = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/tokens/' + address, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  if (fetchedUrl) {
    var json = JSON.parse(fetchedUrl.getContentText());
    if (json) {
      output = json.data.price.substring(0,15);
    }
  }
  // Grace period to not overload
  Utilities.sleep(1000);

  return unescapeHTML(output);
}

var htmlEntities = {
  nbsp:  ' ',
  cent:  '¢',
  pound: '£',
  yen:   '¥',
  euro:  '€',
  dollar:  '$',
  copy:  '©',
  reg:   '®',
  lt:    '<',
  gt:    '>',
  mdash: '–',
  ndash: '-',
  quot:  '"',
  amp:   '&',
  apos:  '\''
};

function unescapeHTML(str) {
    return str.replace(/\&([^;]+);/g, function (entity, entityCode) {
        var match;

        if (entityCode in htmlEntities) {
            return htmlEntities[entityCode];
        } else if (match = entityCode.match(/^#x([\da-fA-F]+)$/)) {
            return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(match[1], 16));
        } else if (match = entityCode.match(/^#(\d+)$/)) {
            return String.fromCharCode(~~match[1]);
        } else {
            return entity;
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You still have "**rowRef**" in your script which is bound to the relative position of BTC price. I cleared out your script and there you go, can you please try the below script and let me know.

```
function RefreshImports() {
    var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
    if (!lock.tryLock(5000)) return; 

    var id = "1IVUjHDRxJiWw8H1LYY_IY0_ydwZ4F3qfSHKcKLa78Bw";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Profit/Loss");

    var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
    var formulas = dataRange.getFormulas();
    var content = "";
    var now = new Date();
    var time = now.getTime();
    var re = /.*[^a-z0-9]import(?:xml|data|feed|html|range|regex|json)\(.*/gi;
    var re2 = /((\?|&)(update=[0-9]*))/gi;

    for (var row=0; row<formulas.length; row++) {
        for (var col=0; col<formulas[0].length; col++) {
        content = formulas[row][col];
        if (content != "") {
            var match = content.search(re);
            if (match !== -1 ) {
            var url = sheet.getRange(row + 1, col).getValue();

            if (url != "") {
                var updatedContent = url.toString().replace(re2,"?update=" + time);
                if (updatedContent == url) {
                // No querystring exists yet in url
                updatedContent = url.toString() + "?update=" + time;
                }
                // Update url in formula with querystring param
                sheet.getRange(row + 1, col).setValue(updatedContent);

                Utilities.sleep(250);
            }
            }
        }
        }
    }

    // Done refresh; release the lock.
    lock.releaseLock();     

    //var dateStr = now.toLocaleDateString("en-GB", { timeZone: 'Lebanon/Beirut' });
    var timeStr = now.toLocaleTimeString("en-GB", { timeZone: 'Lebanon/Beirut' });

    // Show last updated time on sheet somewhere
    sheet.getRange(14,2).setValue("Rates were last updated at " + timeStr);
}

function importRegex(url, regexInput) {
  var output = '';
  var fetchedUrl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  if (fetchedUrl) {
    var html = fetchedUrl.getContentText();
    if (html.length && regexInput.length) {
      output = html.match(new RegExp(regexInput, 'i'))[1];
    }
  }
  // Grace period to not overload
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  return unescapeHTML(output);
}

function importJson(address) {
  var output = '';
  var fetchedUrl = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/tokens/' + address, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  if (fetchedUrl) {
    var json = JSON.parse(fetchedUrl.getContentText());
    if (json) {
      output = json.data.price.substring(0,15);
    }
  }
  // Grace period to not overload
  Utilities.sleep(1000);

  return unescapeHTML(output);
}

var htmlEntities = {
  nbsp:  ' ',
  cent:  '¢',
  pound: '£',
  yen:   '¥',
  euro:  '€',
  dollar:  '$',
  copy:  '©',
  reg:   '®',
  lt:    '<',
  gt:    '>',
  mdash: '–',
  ndash: '-',
  quot:  '"',
  amp:   '&',
  apos:  '\''
};

function unescapeHTML(str) {
    return str.replace(/\&([^;]+);/g, function (entity, entityCode) {
        var match;

        if (entityCode in htmlEntities) {
            return htmlEntities[entityCode];
        } else if (match = entityCode.match(/^#x([\da-fA-F]+)$/)) {
            return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(match[1], 16));
        } else if (match = entityCode.match(/^#(\d+)$/)) {
            return String.fromCharCode(~~match[1]);
        } else {
            return entity;
        }
    });
};
```